# How to enable Reader Mode / Distill Page with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I'd like to use the new Reader Mode or 'Distill Page' feature in Chromium / Chrome 75 via Puppeteer.

I know that I can enable the feature flag via `args:["--enable-reader-mode=true"]` in `puppeteer.launch()`.

What I don't understand, is how to trigger the distill page feature from puppeteer once a page is loaded.

Use case: taking a screenshoot of a page in reader mode.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [reader mode feature got removed from chrome](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/12/20/chrome-beta-80-removes-experimental-reader-mode-and-gesture-navigation-deprecates-ftp-support-and-more/).

You still can use some [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-readability) to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: None forked version https://github.com/mozilla/readability